# How do I find the number in a specific decimal place?

Tags: python, floating-point

For example, I want to get "8" from 1227.827 and "4" from 8.46 using the same code. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Did you try calling the math.modf(num) function, it will return the fraction and integer parts of the input num as a tuple. you could then get the first digit of the fraction part.

Comment: Any quick solution will certainly encounter rounding resulting in a questionable answer.  Some floating point value have [100s](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) of digits.  How exact do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the number to a string, split it at the `.`, take the first character of the second split:

```
number = 1227.827 
int(str(number).split(".")[1][0])
```

> 8

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize I could do it with only one line of code

Answer (score 0):

For decimal places, use negative numbers

```
def nth_digit(x: float, n: int):
    x /= 10 ** n
    x %= 10
    return round(x - 0.5)


print(nth_digit(1227.827, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you want to get the index of the occurences of the integer or the sum of occurences.

In both cases you need casting to string because a integer is one value while a string is an array of chars under the hood.

This finds the index of the first occurence of 8:

```py
>>> get_index = lambda x, y: str(x).find(str(y))
>>> get_index(8.46, 4)
2
>>> get_index(1227.827, 8)
5
```